# Wkhtmltopdf margin (top and bottom)

Tags: linux, pdf, ubuntu, margin, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf 0.10.0 rc2 on a: Linux 3.2.0-24-generic #38-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux

I can't create PDFs with `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` (no errors)

I'm using the command below:

```
wkhtmotopdf -T 50 -B 50 http://google.com ./test.pdf
wkhtmotopdf --margin-top 50 --margin-bottom 50 page.html ./test.pdf
```

When I try this:

```
wkhtmotopdf -L 50 -R 50 -T 50 -B 50 page.html ./test.pdf
```

Margin left and right works perfect (still no margin-top or margin-bottom). It doesn't matter which URL or page I convert.

### EDIT:

It looks like it's a bug. For the people who still want some margin-top/margin-bottom.
Try using the header-html/footer-html feature:

> > Just realised that the clipping problem is fixed by adding the header-spacing and footer-spacing parameters:

`wkhtmotopdf -L 50 -R 50 -T 50 -B 50 http://google.com --header-html blank.html --header-spacing 5 --footer-html blank.html --footer-spacing 5 ./test.pdf`